# YII widget access model - I need a value from DB in my layout

Tags: php, yii, yii-widgets

In a layout I need to display number of notifications.

what is the right way of doing it? I'm thinking to create a widget for it but is accessing DB while rendering view correct?

Comment: If you are creating a widget for it, then your DB access should be in the widget not in the view.

Comment: of course DB access will be in a widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is ok to create a widget for this needs.

After done, it is ok to call it from layout.

You can even use caching in order not to bother DB too often.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/17/how-to-make-use-of-a-fragment-cache/

Finally: I would recommend writing widget and using it with fragmental caching.